# Изменение protected field вне сборки

Tags: c#

Можно ли изменить значение вне сборки?

```
[SerializeField]
protected float walkSpeed = 1f;

[SerializeField]
protected float runSpeed = 3f;
```

Comment: отнаследуйтесь от этого класса и меняйте

Comment: @tym32167 тогда вроде же просто копия создается, а мне оригинал нужно сменить

Comment: Копия чего? Вы о чем вообще?

Comment: @tym32167 копия переменной.Вот например я тут изменил, но оригинал так и остался со старым значением https://pastebin.com/KZGkgrV7

Comment: Я не могу поглядеть ничего по ссылкам, если хотите добавить код - добавьте его текстом в вопрос. А ещё лучше  опишите, какую проблему решаете, так как есть подозрение, что у вас XY проблема.